# Can two cursors with same name exist in two different procesesses?

Tags: database, oracle, proc

Can two cursors with same name exist in two different procesesses?

Let us say I have an binary alert_sender which uses cusror name GET_ALERT_CURSOR to get the data from database, and the same cursor name exist in another binary alert_closer which closes the alerts.

Both binaries will be running on same machine and connects to the same database.

Is there any problem with this?

I am getting errors like this in my process.

H_ALERT_PROCESSOR:ERROR_LEVEL:2016/10/04 05:10:55:error opening H_CURSOR: **ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1**

**ORA-01000: maximum**  | Time Delta: 0.003 | Total: 0.017 | (file/line = HAlertDataPuller.PC:176)

H_ALERT_PROCESSOR:ERROR_LEVEL:2016/10/04 05:25:55:error opening H_CURSOR: **ORA-01003: no statement parsed**

H_ALERT_PROCESSOR:ERROR_LEVEL:2016/10/04 05:40:55:error opening H_CURSOR: ORA-01003: no statement parsed

H_ALERT_PROCESSOR:ERROR_LEVEL:2016/10/04 05:55:55:error opening H_CURSOR: ORA-01003: no statement parsed

H_ALERT_PROCESSOR:ERROR_LEVEL:2016/10/04 06:10:55:**error opening H_CURSOR: ORA-01003: no statement parsed**

Comment: It's really hard to help you diagnose the issue when you haven't provided us with any example code etc. If you need more help with this, you're going to have to provide us with much more information - remember, we can't see your database, we don't know your data or schema structure and we definitely don't know your business logic, so the more info you can provide, the better.

Answer (score 1):

`Yes` they can `exist`, but if they run at `same time` then there would be issue.

Lets consider your example:

When your process `alert_sender`  started and it opened the cursor `GET_ALERT_CURSOR` , that means in the buffer its remains active till the sql processing takes place. 
At the same time your second process `alert_closer` started and it also tried to open a cursor with the same name `GET_ALERT_CURSOR`, hence the earlier definition of cursor still remains active and the SQL engine 
finds that its already open and throws errors like

> ORA-06511 - Cursor already open.

Incase your previous cursor completes & cursor not closed and other starts then

> ora-01000 maximum open cursors exceeded

and so on.

Comment: ok.. from your view this can happen between two processes, actually ours is an big application and we have n instances of same code.. like alert_sender1, alert_sender_2... aler_sender_n (all comipled and link with same code and in sam environment). So what do you think is the solution for this.

Comment: I am sorry but how do we create dependencies?

Comment: You need to revisit your application architecture and need to look how you are calling multiple instances. If using scheduler then need to create depndencies such that no 2 cursors overlap. Look which is more feasible. If not dependencies when may be changin name will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no issues, it's like having the same local variable defined in different methods, they can run on the same machine, and in the same application.

Comment: Were there any changes to the tables used by those cursors?

Comment: I am not sure, may be there are changes, but how does that impact my problem?

Comment: If the cursor is defined as select * and the table definition changed, you can bump into the error you mentioned above

Comment: oh.. ok..  but I am selecting individual columns.

Comment: Do you use any columns or aliases that might be reserved keywords? `OPEN v_customer_recs FOR
         SELECT sc.EVENT_ID,
                sc.OPEN_DATE,
                ND.DESCRIPTION AS COMMENT,  -- This will cause the error
                SC.BC_DATE
           FROM CUSTOMERS sc, NEW_DESCRIPTION ND
will result in a ORA-01003: no statement parsed`

Comment: This can also happen if you are missing a grant on an object to the user running the process.

Comment: can you please look into my other thread for question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043605/when-do-a-prepare-query-fails-in-pro-c

Comment: I don't think I have any reserved keywords. I had the query in above link.